# If I use Google Analytics can I delete my IIS logs?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003

MY IIS logs are taking up a lot of space and I don't know what to do with them. If Google Analytics is meeting all of my needs can I just delete all my IIS logs and turn off the daily creation of them?

I've spent the past hour hour or so understand what IIS logs are and what they do. I've seen that a lot of people delete them after "x" number of days, or they archive and delete? Do I need to archive and delete them? I didn't even know they existed until today, so needless to say I'm not really using them, so I'm hoping I can just delete them this once and turn off future creations of them?

Can you let me know if this is a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remember that web server logs can tell you lots of things GA can't. For example, they can easily tell you who downloaded which non-html files. Or if you have a nasty string of HTTP 500 errors that prevent pages from being rendered.

All that said, there is no technical reason why one would need to keep them. We actually disable IIS logging on some internal servers entirely so as not to have to clean up after it.

Comment: Any ideas on the best cleanup method? Right now I'm currently planning on creating or finding a windows service that will archive and delete files after a certain period of time. Maybe that is easier said than done.

Comment: but powershell isn't automated. I don't want to have to check the server every month to delete logs.

Comment: Powershell + scheduled tasks are pretty automated

Comment: oh ok, I get what you're saying

Answer (score 1):

You might want to to archive them just in case.  For example, if something odd happens it is always useful to have the logs.

If you are just monitoring stats Google analytics does not require them.

Comment: Now I'm understanding that GA is just run on the page so if I get a page 500 error GA won't help me with that, but the IIS logs can.

Comment: Yes, that's a good example.  Perhaps you could only log errors?